# No elimina el registro en mi BD que selecciono

Tags: php, php5

Este es mi modulo de consultas, donde tengo **las opciones de modificar y eliminar** , el problema que tengo es que cuando le doy click en el boton de eliminar solo sale el mensaje del script  "REGISTRO ELIMINADO" pero en realidad no me elimina los datos de mi BD.

Gracias / Saludos.

```html
        <?php

    require("connect_db.php");
    $sql=("SELECT * FROM ctg_turno");
 
                //la variable  $mysqli viene de connect_db que lo traigo con el require("connect_db.php");
    $query=mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);

    echo "<table border='1'; class='table table-hover';>";
     echo "<tr class='warning'>";
         echo "<td>ID</td>";
      echo "<td>Turno</td>";
      echo "<td>Horas por Jornada</td>";
      echo "<td>Actualizar</td>";
      echo "<td>Eliminar</td>";
           echo "</tr>";

       
   ?>
     
  <?php 
     while($arreglo=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
       echo "<tr class='success'>";
         echo "<td>$arreglo[0]</td>";
     echo "<td>$arreglo[1]</td>";
         echo "<td>$arreglo[2]</td>";
      
                        echo "<td><a href='actualizar_turno.php?idctg_turno=$arreglo[0]'><img src='images/actualizar.gif' class='img-rounded'></td>";
          echo "<td><a href='turno_edit.php?idctg_turno=$arreglo[0]'><img src='images/eliminar.png' class='img-rounded'/></a></td>";
      

      
     echo "</tr>";
    }
    

    echo "</table>";
  
                                 extract($_GET);
     if(@$idctg_turno){
  
      $sqlborrar="DELETE FROM ctg_turno WHERE idctg_turno=$idctg_turno";
      $resborrar=mysqli_query($mysqli,$sqlborrar);
      echo '<script>alert("REGISTRO ELIMINADO")</script> ';    
      echo "<script>location.href='turno_edit.php'</script>";
     }
     

   ?>
```

Comment: @ShadowPaz Segun yo el @ es un control de errores, lo que pretendo es que me cache el error si llegara a tener uno.

Comment: @ShadowPaz Exacto, no se si en esa parte lo estoy haciendo bien.

Comment: @ShadowPaz Si quito el @ me sale el siguiente error   Notice: Undefined variable: idctg_turno in C:\xampp\htdocs\turno_edit.php on line 136

Comment: los que hace en este modulo que solo se consultan, ya que los declaro en otro modulo que es el de inserción, por eso me sale que no esta definido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La función que estás utilizando, [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php), devuelve FALSE en caso de error de la sentencia ¿Por qué no controlas esto, y por otro lado imprimes *$sqlborrar* en pantalla?

También puedes imprimir el último error de [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.error.php) si te ayuda en algo.

En un primer vistazo, no veo el problema (sobre todo porque dices que te sale la alerta, así que se está ejecutando), a ver si mis consejos te sirven.

Comment: si imprimo el $sqlborrar  me sale mi select con el id que esta asignado correctamente    DELETE FROM ctg_turno WHERE idctg_turno=3

Comment: Entiendo ¿Y $resborrar? ¿Es True o False?

Comment: $resborrar es True

Comment: Vaya, bueno, asegurémonos de que 1. Puedes ejecutar el query directamente sobre la base de datos y funciona bien (Copia y pega lo que me has puesto en tu gestor de BD y mira si funciona) 2. El usuario que estás usando para la conexión tiene privilegios para borrar.

Comment: Ejecute el query en mi gestor de BD y me marca un error   #1451 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`admon`.`trabajador`, CONSTRAINT `trabajador_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`idctg_turno`) REFERENCES `ctg_turno` (`idctg_turno`))

Comment: ¡Genial! Ahí está el problema. Simplemente te está diciendo que en la tabla "trabajador" hay filas que referencian el valor (3) de la columna idctfg_turno de tu tabla ctg_turno. Tienes que borrar las filas que referencian este valor antes de borrar el del turno :) O puedes eliminar la cláve foránea, ya depende de con lo que estés trabajando.

Comment: Tienes mucha razón, solo que hay un problema ya que mi tabla ctg_turno depende de mi tabla trabajador, hay alguna forma de eliminarlo y que tambien se elimine de la otra tabla trabajador?

Comment: Esto ya pasaría a temas de SQL, pero en resumen: Si quieres borrar los trabajadores, tienes que hacerlo en una query anterior. En realidad sería muy parecida a la que tienes ahora (Delete * from trabajador where idctg_turno = $idctg_turno), y luego te aseguras de que su resultado es TRUE antes de ejecutar la que tienes ahora.

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias